# Detach site from multisite (turn off multisite)

Tags: multisite, migration

I have a series of wordpress sites which live under one multisite:

-**My multisite**

- Website A
- Website B
- Website C
- Website D

I am going to be rebuilding the site and as part of the new build, we don't need the multisite confiugration but I need all the content of one of the site as it's rather large.

Essentially, what I want to do is have '*Website C*' as a single site on it's own, websites '*A*','*B*' and '*D*' can be deleted.

Any sort of multisite functionality needs to be removed and it needs to work as a single WP site.

The domains are as follows:

- Website A - [www.website.com/de](http://www.website.com/de)
- Website B - [www.website.com/es](http://www.website.com/es)
- Website C - [www.website.com/](http://www.website.com/)
- Website D - [www.website.com/ru](http://www.website.com/ru)

This should hopefully make any database changes easier as the new site will be:
[www.website.com/](http://www.website.com/)

Comment: I'd guess you can just take the website C database tables plus the wp_user and wp_usertables from the network and that would just work? I don't know how wp_content/uploads would work though: you'll need the site-specific upload folder but I don't know if you'll then need to rewrite all of the URLs in pages and settings. Or just leave all the old files in the site-specific folder maybe.

Comment: Or you could always try exporting and reimporting the site if you didn't want to try and fix the database and files manually.

Comment: I added another point onto my original question based on your comment. Having them sit on the same domain might make it easier. 
Will website 'C' not be set up as a multisite? Is there anything I need to do to set it to a single WP site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just export all content from the site you want to keep. Then create a new WP instance, import that exported data, tweak as required.

Once the site is OK, make the new site active for the desired domain name (in your hosting, point the domain to the new site's folder). No messing with databases required.

**Added 31 July 2020**

Another way: Use the Clone plugin from Automatic to export subsite. Install the plugin as superadmin. Then admin to the subsite and use the Clone plugin to back up everything.

Create a new WP instance (single-site), then install the Clone plugin there.  Then import the backup you made of the subsite into the new site via the plugin. Make sure  you remember the admin credentials, as everything on the new site will be replaced during the restore process.

Everything from subsite will now be on the new site including themes, plugins, settings and content.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This sounds like it could work but I need to transfer everything, for example plugin data (forms etc.), images, users etc. Export and Import only does posts doesn't it?

Comment: See revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the requested changes might take more like a manual effect. Like separating db's for each other site. Before that identify the which db belong to which site. When you access network site(Network admin->Sites) hover over site edit on respective site domain, on the bottom you can see the see site id's[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80hH9.png). So you can separately download these db's uploads on it your respective new site db's. Only concern would be the users tables(**wp_usermeta**, **wp_users**) because it sharing all users in these 2 tables. So uploads these on sites db and remove the unwanted users from the sites.
I believe this helps you.

[image]

[image]